# fontfamily on the picker item not working on react native?

Tags: react-native, picker, font-family, react-boilerplate

the font family for react native picker is not working

```
<Picker   itemStyle={{backgroundColor: "red",fontFamily:'ArbFONTS-GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT',}} >
      <Picker.Item fontFamily="ArbFONTS-GE_SS_TEXT_LIGHT"  label={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} value={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} />
      <Picker.Item  label={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} value={I18n.translate("reclamation_sujet")} />
      </Picker>
```